# Model Object From Both Core Data & External Source

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, model

I am building an app where my primary model objects can either be fetched from a Core Data store or from an external source (public API via internet - > JSON - > object).  I'm new to Core Data so my question is can I just take my model object as it stands now and make its superclass NSManagedObject?  I'd guess that I'd need to make sure my model's properties match the names and types of the data model entities for this to happen.  I don't want to have to use two different model objects in the app - one when I fetch from the core data store and one when I fetch from the internet API.

Is there anything else I'd need to do to make my already built model objects compatible for use with core data?

Any guidance or advice would be much appreciated.

Regards,

Craig

Answer (score 0):

You can add some business logic to your object (subclass of `NSManagedObject`) to enable to creation of such an object from data (ie an `NSDictionary` of values to be used). The crux will be deciding whether you want those objects managed/saved to your local datastore or not.

I highly recommend becoming familiar with `NSManagedObjectContext`: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in a couple of products is just deal with core data objects, and initialize them from data that I pull from the web service. That way you only have apples. Another option would be to make a protocol that defines the behavior of the analogous classes. You would be tempted to make one the subclass of the other, but that could get complicated, depending on your persistence requirements.